# Checking session variables on Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that periodically (every 3 seconds or so) checks for content updates through Ajax, receiving them through a .js file that runs as a script to replace a specific area of the page. The .js file looks something like this:

```
$('div#content').html('<p>New content.</p>');
```

The problem is that I want to check the .js file against a few PHP session variables to modify the content before it is displayed, particularly to see if the user is logged in or not. In short, I have to execute PHP code inside the .js file so that it is modified for the end user when called using Ajax.

I cannot rename the extension of the .js file to .php because the .js file is created through the use of PHP code and I am not allowed to create .php files on my server.

I cannot run a separate PHP script that outputs the contents of the .js file because the .js file is created and updated whenever a change is made to the content, not during the Ajax call (except for the session variables portion). There is also the problem of session variables of the current user being used to create and update content that is suppose to be meant for everybody else.

Currently, the best solution I have found is from [here](http://www.kavoir.com/2010/07/how-to-execute-run-php-code-inside-javascript-files.html). It involves creating a .htaccess file to parse all .js files as PHP.

Does anybody else have better solutions (or maybe even workarounds that would prevent this problem from happening)?

Comment: You shouldn't mix php/js together.  The fact that they run in different contexts makes that ugly.  Instead, create a php file that you can do an ajax request for that gets the contents of the session variable in question

Comment: Do you mean that I should do an ajax request to a PHP file from within my .js file to access my session variables? I haven't thought of that, but isn't that weird or inefficient since I'm making an ajax request inside another?

Comment: I looked it up. Seems like it's okay to do ajax requests from inside another ajax request. Thank you for your help!